# How to compute Bayesian Network from microarray Gene Pix data using free software?

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor, bayesian-networks

I have tried to use MeV26, Bayesia software and R for making Bayesian network from 26 Columns of gene expression microarray numbers (.csv file, 652 genes there). Does anybody experienced can advise what software and scripts to use and what books and tutorials are best for that task? Are there any Python or Ruby libraries for that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Software Tools:**

The easiest way would be to use [WEKA](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/). Simply import your data into WEKA, select Bayesian/ Bayesian Network (BN) as your classifier option, learn a structure and look at your classification performance.

The second would be to use R with the [bnlearn](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bnlearn/index.html) package.

In general, you can find BN libraries in all major languages. I am not familiar with Ruby but Python has [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pbnt.berlios/).

But again, I would advise first using WEKA, as it will give you results almost instantaneously, which you can use later to benchmark your more detailed results that you obtain by getting your hands dirty / coding in whatever language.

**Reading:**

Obviously, there are many articles published on BNs but you may not have access to them and I presume you don't want to pay to buy a book straight-away. MatLab BNT's developer K. Murphy has a nice introductory [article](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Bayes/bnintro.html). Furthermore the BNT's [manual](http://bnt.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/usage.html) itself provides a nice, brief and hands-on (if you have MatLab) introduction to the use of BNs.